# BigQuery SQL Joining Several Tables with Different Matching Columns

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join, logistic-regression

I have 9 tables of data saved in BigQuery containing calculated values from the same source, and I would like to join all of these tables together into one big table. They all overlap in at least the following columns of game_id, game_date, and candidate_id(which can be used to match them all up properly), and proceed to then have their own unique columns of calculated results from the original dataset.

I'm a bit confused on how to go about this though because some of the tables overlap in additional ways, while the others do not. Using Table 9 as like a "base" table to compare the others too, Tables 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 9 all share simply the three columns listed above. Table 8 however also shares with table 9 the columns of start_frame_id, end_frame_id, and frame_id in addition to the original three columns. Even more so, tables 1 and 2 share with Table 9 everything Table 8 shares in addition to the column dist_to-defender.

Not including any code because these are simply all stored tables in BigQuery, an easy way to refer to the tables would be table_1, table_2, etc. for code examples I assume?

**Would this be easier to just do manually in excel?**

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- I'm sure you can explain with just 2 or 3 tables.  What does logistic regression have to do with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you want `full join` and `using`:

```
select game_id, game_date, candidate_id,
       t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3 . . .   -- the other columns you want
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (game_id, game_date, candidate_id) full join
     t3
     using (game_id, game_date, candidate_id) full join
     . . .;
```

You can expand the logic to include additional columns, if appropriate, for matching.

However, it might be better to write single query that generates what you want, combining the nine queries you already have.  Then, you can get rid of the nine queries.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Will this properly align things automatically? To clarify, would this automatically put something with the row that shares the same candidate_id from the other table?

Comment: @Jacob . . . Yes, assuming the other columns match.